# Trying to get property of non-object CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to CodeIgniter. I am using a form with Form Validation. My problem is when I press "Edit details", an ERROR appears. "Trying to get property of non-object".

This is my view: user/edit_user.php

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">

</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h1>EDIT YOUR DETAILS</h1>

        <?php if (validation_errors()){ ?>
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <?= validation_errors() ?>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>


        <form method="POST" action="<?=base_url().'user/do_edit_user'?>">
        <input value="<?= $user->id ?>" name="id" type="hidden">
        <input value="<?= $user->name ?>" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name"> <br>
        <input value="<?= $user->password ?>" type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"> <br>
        <input value="<?= $user->email ?>" type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email"> <br>
        <input value="<?= $user->number ?>" type="number" name="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Number"> <br>
        <input value="<?= $user->university ?>" type="text" name="university" class="form-control" placeholder="University"> <br>
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
<div class="col-md-3">

</div>
```

This is my controller: User.php

```
 public function edit_details(){
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);

    $data['user'] = $this->AdminModel->getUser($id);

    $this->load->view('includes/header');
    $this->load->view('includes/navbar');
    $this->load->view('users/edit_user', $data);
    $this->load->view('includes/footer');
}

public function display(){

    $cond = array (
    'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
    'password' => sha1($this->input->post('password'))
    );

    $data['user'] = $this->UserModel->getUser($cond);

    if(!($data))
    {
        redirect('user/index');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('includes/header');
        $this->load->view('includes/navbar');
        $this->load->view('users/display', $data);
        $this->load->view('includes/footer');
    }

}
```

And my last controller for do_edit_user`

```
public function do_edit_user(){
    $id = $this->input->post('id');

    $user = array(
        'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
        'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
        'number' => $this->input->post('number'),
        'university' => $this->input->post('university')
    );

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required|min_length[3]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|min_length[8]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('number', 'Number', 'max_length[11]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('university', 'University', 'min_length[8]');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->edit_details();
    }
    else
    {
        $this->AdminModel->updateUser($id, $user);
        redirect('user/display');
    }
}

public function activate(){
    $cond = array(
        'activation_code' => $this->uri->segment(3)
        );

    if(!($this->UserModel->checkAccount($cond)==null)){
        echo 'successfully registered email';
    }else{
        echo 'invalid';
    }
}
```

What am I missing or need to change? Sorry for my format if this is wrong. Correct me if there was wrong in my post and code.

Actual Error is A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: users/edit_user.php

Line Number: 16
Line Number: 17
Line Number: 18
Line Number: 19
Line Number: 20
Line Number: 21

My UserModel

```
public function insertUser($user){
    $this->db->insert('tbluser', $user);
}

public function checkAccount($cond){
    $this->db->where($cond);
    $this->db->update('tbluser', array('status'=>'active'));
    $q = $this->db->get_where('tbluser', $cond);
    return $q->row();
}

public function getUser($cond){
    $this->db->where($cond);
    $q = $this->db->get('tbluser');
    return $q->row();
}

public function getUser($id){
    $q = $this->db->get_where('tbluser', array('id' => $id));
    return $q->row();
}
```

Comment: Please post the actual error message.

Comment: i edited my post @OptimusCrime

Comment: which one is line 16 in edit_user.php? Is it <form ... form tag opening line? If so, try appending user ID at the end of action url, like this:   base_url().'user/do_edit_user/'.$user->id

Comment: Sorry no, line 16 starts with <input value... then up to the last input value> @VipinKr.Singh

Comment: OK try outputting $user object at the top of edit_user.php view, by using: <pre><? print_r($user) ?></pre> and check whether  this object has all the properties that you are using in view file and also post your model's code for getUser($id) function, $this->AdminModel->getUser($id);

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because you return a string or an array from `UserModel->getUser()` method, like `return $query->result_array()` or `return $string`, to `$data['user']` in User controller instead of `return $query->result()`. Check it.

**Update 1**

I'm newbie too, but you can try this if you still need help:

User.php (change to)

```
$email => $this->input->post('email');                         //this
$password => sha1($this->input->post('password'));             //this

$data['user'] = $this->UserModel->getUser($email, $password);  //or this
```

and your UserModel.php (change to)

```
public function getUser($email, $password){ // and this are
$this->db->where('email' => $email);        // not a
$this->db->where('password' => $password);  // nesessary changes but you can try it
$q = $this->db->get('tbluser');
return $q->result(); // try result() instead of row()
}
```

Comment: Where should I put that return? I don't know where. Im new.

Comment: Please, add your UserModel code so we can see what data you want to pass by getUser() method.

Answer (score 0):

You should handle the null of $user object.

Following things are cheats and will not give you errors.

`<?=@$user->id` using a @ sign if you are not sure about $user object

OR

Assign the user to a object variable.

```
$data['user'] = new stdClass();
$data['user'] = $this->UserModel->getUser($cond);
```

Comment: Where should I put that new object variable? In my controller or view?

Comment: in your controller

Answer (score -1):

```
$user['id']
$user['name']
$user['password'] 
$user['email']
$user['number']
$user['university']
```

try to do like this when you return row_array() or result()

Comment: I've tried this and the error is gone. But the problem now is when I click Edit button, the value does not return for name, email, number etc.. or it is all blank.